# How to get the objects from child model to a django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created child ('Bid') model related to a parent(Post) model in my Django project. I also created a BidForm which I have added in my B_Bid.view so that type-2 users can bid on a particular Post created by type-1 users. When bids are created to for a particular Post, I wanted to show them all distinguished with that post in my template. So, I did as in below code. But in my page, I couldn't able to get the list of the bids for a particular Post. I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_id

class Bid(models.Model):

    bid_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=1, related_name='bids' )
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accept_bid", kwargs={"bid_id": self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.amount

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount
```

Views.py:

```
def place_bid(request):

    form = BidForm(request.POST or None)

    if  form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        print(form.cleaned_data.get("amount"))
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

        queryset = Post.objects.all()

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'loggedin_truck/live_bid_truck.html', context)

def live_bids(request):
    post_queryset = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids')

    context = {
        "post_queryset": post_queryset,
        "title": "List",
    }
    return render(request, 'loggedin_load/live_bids.html', context)
```

form.py:

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ["amount"]
```

live_bids.html:

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
{{post.post_id}}
{% for bid in post.bids.all %}
{{bid.bid_id}}
{{bid.amount}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is there any `bids` associated with `post`? Are you able to get in on Django view?

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you getting an error? Are you sure you actually have data to show?

Comment: BTW, it should be `prefetch_related("bids")` instead of `select_related('bids')`

Comment: @RohitJain I associated the bids with the post as in my place_bid view. Actually, I forget to change it to prefetch_related in my question. when I using prefetch_related i couldn't able to get the list of bids that are associated with the post. Maybe I left something. Could you help me in fixing this!!

Comment: @MadWombat i didn't get any error. But the list of bids that are associated with a particular post shows empty. And i can see the list in my database.

Comment: If you start Django shell (python manage.py shell), import your models and do `for post in Post.objects.all(): print(post.bids.all())` do you see your bids?

Comment: @MadWombat instead of three dots(...), i could see nothing

Comment: @sumanth Hit enter twice, after that code.

Comment: @RohitJain now []. That means my bid list is empty r8? But i can see the bid list in my database. How could it possible?

Comment: Try getting `Bid` first, for the id you see in DB. And then see `bid.post`. What do you get?

Comment: File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 169, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 387, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
app1.models.doesnotexist: Post matching query does not exist.

Comment: @RohitJain I stuck at this point from last 4 days. I am new to django and it is hard to move forward. Could you please help solving this issue!!

Comment: @RohitJain you told me to import Bid model and then for the bid_id i see in DB print bid.post. How can i write a syntax for the 'bid_id'  in Bid.objects.all():

Comment: @sumanth It's clear that there is a `bid`, linking to non-existent `post`. as per your error. Please check that in DB. Just do a `Left Outer Join` from `Bid` to `Post` table, on `post_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

To access child records, use

> foo_set.all

Change your code to this

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
{{post.post_id}}
{% for bid in post.bid_set.all %}
```